# Any way to apply .vimrc to a specific tmux session?

Tags: vim, tmux

I am sharing one account with other teammates in a Ubuntu server. Are there any ways to apply vim settings (using .vimrc or other techniques) only to the tmux session created by myself?

Comment: ... alright, vim is a programmer's tool. But this may be more suitable on [vi.se].

Comment: Isn't the solution obviously "don't share the user account"?

Comment: Set your `$HOME` environment variable to point into a subdirectory? `HOME=$HOME/mydirectory vim ...` (and then your vim config goes in `$HOME/mydirectory/.vim`, etc)

Comment: In your `vimrc`, write: `if exists(lol) source ~/.yourOwnVimrc endif`. And execute your `vim` command like this: `vim --cmd 'let lol=1'` when you want to open Vim.

Answer (score 0):

According to `vim --help`

```
-u <vimrc>        Use <vimrc> instead of any .vimrc
```

You could run `vim -u /path/to/.myvimrc` or give it an alias to apply specific settings.